# Get count of unmapped records when using a mapping table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, join, query

I have 3 tables as such

#### Product

| Product ID | Product Details |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |

#### Vendor

| Vendor ID | Vendor Details |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |

#### Product Vendors

| Product ID | Vendor ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

How would I go about finding the number of products that are **not** mapped to a specific vendor.

I tried:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(pr.id) AS product_count
FROM
    products pr
LEFT JOIN vendor_product_map vp ON
    pr.id = vp.product
LEFT JOIN vendors vv ON
    vp.vendor = vv.id
WHERE
    vv.id = 3 AND vp.vendor IS NULL
```

but that doesn't seem right. Any help is appreciated

Edit:
For the above data, the expected results would be

#### Not Mapped Products

| Vendor ID | Product Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 |

In short not mapped product count = total products - count of mapped products for a specific vendor, I'll be specifying the vendor ID so the result set will have only 1 row. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using `not exists` and a subquery.

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(pr.id) AS product_count
FROM
    products pr
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        vendor_product_map vp
    WHERE
        vp.product = pr.id AND vp.vendor = 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that a product will always be properly linked to a vendor, you could use an INNER JOIN, and simply filter out results where vender_id = 3.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS product_count
FROM products AS pr
    INNER JOIN vendor_product_map AS vp ON pr.id = vp.product
WHERE vp.vendor <> 3
```

If vendor might ever be NULL, and you want those results as well, you'd want to stick with a LEFT JOIN, like this...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS product_count
FROM products AS pr
    LEFT JOIN vendor_product_map AS vp ON pr.id = vp.product
WHERE vp.vendor <> 3 OR vp.vendor IS NULL
```